# Magento2.3 install extention via composer but in app/code

Tags: magento2.3, extensions, composer

I have an extension which was installed in **app/code** and override from **app/code**, now I have only the zip for the composer installation, is it a way to install this extension by composer but in **app/code**/extensionsuppliername/extensionname instead of **vendor/**? 
Thank you in advance
ps: in case of minus please let me know why so I can improve my post

Comment: Can you please share the folder structure of the extension installed in the vendor?

Comment: it's not installed in vendor/ it installed in app/code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have two possible ways**

**#1: Please remove the app/code/extensionsuppliername/extensionname then add composer the composer entry and run the composer update, setup:upgrade**

**Note: If you go with #1** After removal of app/code/extensionsuppliername/extensionname, please run setup:upgrade. If no issues found then it will be fine.

**#2: Download the module from zip and replace it in app/code/extensionsuppliername**

Comment: unfortunately, 1 is not working so I will go with 2 but then I will need the zip from mageworx

Comment: Yup, you should need zip. @SylvainMichel

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a normal scenario the plugin you are trying to install should have the folder structure, so it should automatically place it in app/code.

If you are trying to install it by hand you can always look inside a controller to see what the path should have been and build the route accordingly.

This seems like a good explanation of what I am trying to say : https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-the-right-way-to-install-external-modules/

Comment: in composer, case is mostly in vendor/ instead of app/code for the whole code as they tell on the link :( and this is an update of an extension which is already override via app/code

Comment: In that case you will indeed have to do it by hand I'm afraid. Let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by modifying the composer.json configuration file, more info [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md).